# Override php-fpm pool config values with another file

Tags: configuration, php-fpm, pool

Having to customize the php-fpm pool configuration of a new server, I wonder if it is possible / allowed / recommended to have a new pool file, which name goes alphabetically after the original one, which only has values that override the initial configuration.

The original configuration is in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d` named `www.conf`.

It seems, according to the pages related to the installation, engineers modify directly the original (saving a copy of the initial values). E.g.

```
[www]
...
user www-data
group www-data
pm.max_children 2
```

gives after modification

```
[www]
...
user myapp         ; was www-data
group myapp        ; was www-data
pm.max_children 8  ; was 2
```

But it seems that could be a task to be repeated after the next upgrade of php-fpm (furthermore the configuration is in a `7.0` path, that's worrying).

Instead of modifying the original file, I would like to keep it unchanged, and add another one, say `wwwmyapp.conf` that would declare the same pool, and having only the values that have changed

in `wwwmyapp.conf`

```
[www]        ; same pool!
user myapp
group myapp
pm.max_children 8
```

in `pool.d`, list of files

```
www.conf
wwwmyapp.conf
```

since in `php-fpm.conf` all pool conf files are loaded, the values of `wwwmyapp` will be read after the ones of `www` ( in the same `www` pool ) and should override the first values.

- It seems to work in a few tests and no error reported, but will it work all the time, and for all values?
- Should we overwrite the config file directly instead?

Couldn't find an answer in any doc, even on php.net.

Comment: At least in Debian / Ubuntu based distributions, the upgrade process asks if it should keep the old configuration files or install upgraded ones from package. It will install the new configuration file with a suffix so one can check the changes that way. I assume other package managers have a similar feature. Therefore I think it is a matter of opinion. However, having too pool definitions with the same name doesn't sound like it would work in the future too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Could not find an "official" confirmation from another source, but here is some outcome after doing some research:

Analyzing the source code of `php7.0-fpm` and more specifically `fpm-conf.c`, it appears that

- the main configuration file `php-fpm.conf` is read first [ *fpm_conf_load_ini_file*() ],
- all `include` directives are read in order, giving a list of files thanks to [*glob*()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glob),
- each of the file is parsed by the same *fpm_conf_load_ini_file*(),
- an entry in the file overwrites any previously set value,
- any new `include` will have a recursive call to the includes processing function, and
- the *glob*() function sorts names, by default (no `GLOB_NOSORT` option)

Thus we can assume - at least in this version but this is unlikely to change soon considering the present code - that it is safe to arrange the `pool.d` directory configuration files in alphabetical order ; any previously recorded value being overwritten by an entry with the same name read after.

We have a clean way to handle configuration files for `php-fpm`, keeping the distribution ones untouched, and adding custom files having name alphabetically greater than the packaged ones, that contain the few options that have to be changed.

Comment: +1 for not changing the default configuration. I always have troubles when I use that one for production environment because it gets reverted to defaults while upgrading.

Comment: global FPM overrides under pool.d are possigbe using `[global]` section. e.g. `emergency_restart_threshold`. Tested on php7.1-fpm ubuntu (server 18).

Comment: Also, because default pool name is `www` the only way to override is using pool.d filenames like `wwwsomething` or starting with `x`, `y` or `z`.

Comment: Thanks! I've named my file `z-www-overrides.conf` and it overidden `[www]` pool options!

Comment: @hrvoj3e No, you can actually rename the default `www.conf` as you wish, something like `50-default.conf`, then add your own files, like `10-before.conf` and `70-after.conf`.

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad You could rename but should not. Why? Packages create default files when reinstalling and/or upgrading. It could happen that `www.conf` will be created again at some point in the future and break your setup.

Comment: @hrvoj3e Usually the update creates an `wwws.conf-dist` if one exists, so you could keep an empty `www.conf` in the dir.

Answer (score 3):

In case u have some file like php-overrides.ini you should copy it to

`/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini`

99 prefix is due to order of execution

Comment: `conf.d` overrides cannot override `php-fpm.conf` variables (only in `pool.d/` under `[global]`) *(note to future self)*

Answer (score 2):

### Overriding [www] pool values through custom `.conf` files:

It is possible, and @breaking-not-so-bad [explanation](https://serverfault.com/a/806530/519091) of how config files are loaded is great, I recommend you read it first.

##### But it is definitely worth emphasising the importance of config files naming (as it can be tricky):

> As @hroj3e explained and @istranger exemplified in the comments [above](https://serverfault.com/a/806530/519091)

- If the default pool name is www the only way to override it is using pool.d filenames like wwwsomething or starting with x, y or z - **@hroj3e**
- Named the file`z-www-overrides.conf` and it's overidden `[www]` pool options - **@istranger**

#### An example:

Creating a file `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/z-www-overrides.conf` will override the settings in `php-fpm.conf`:

```php
[www]
user myapp
group myapp
pm.max_children 8
```

Comment: Emphasising the importance of the naming convention and the example. As someone who sets up infrastructure every so often (and that tries to rely on copy-paste and light edits as much as possible), I felt I could have gone through the process faster by having that data available in a more digestible way, which is what I tried to do for others.

However, not bringing brand new insights, I wanted to make as clear as possible that my reply is almost a TL;DR of yours